# Broadcasting FM signals from Android Phone

Tags: android, flutter

Out of curiosity. Is it possible to develop an application that would `broadcast` **FM** signals from an Android phone without the need for any additional hardware?

Nothing so far. I'm hoping someone has already tried to embark on this particular journey.

Answer (score 0):

An FM transmitter is a unique piece of hardware. Most phones don't even have an FM receiver and use headphone wires for this purpose (that is to say, you can't even receive FM signals without extra hardware, let alone broadcast them).